# How to prevent Future from never finishing

Tags: scala, future

Suppose I have multiple tasks that I want to run in parallel.

Each task(method) has an inner recursive function that basically fetches data from a database and saves it in some data storage.

[simplified inner recursive function]

```
 def simplifiedSomeTask(): Unit = {
    @scala.annotation.tailrec
    def get(
        stream: Stream[SomeEntity],
        result: Seq[SomeEntity],
    ): Stream[SomeEntity] = result match {
      case Nil =>
        stream
      case _ =>
        val query = //query to fetch data from database
        get(
          stream append result.toStream,
          query.run.value, // get fetched data from database
        )
    }

    val buffer = collection.mutable.Map.empty[String, String]

    get(
      Stream.empty,
      query.run.value
    ).foreach { r =>
      buffer.put(r.loginId, r.userId)
    }
  }
```

When trying to run A, Future never finishes for some reason.

[A]

```
val f1 =Future { someTask1() }
val f2 =Future { someTask2() }
val f3 =Future { someTask3() }

val f = for {
  _ <- f1 
  _ <- f2 
  _ <- f3 
} yield ()

Await.result(f, Duration.Inf)
```

However, B works(though it does not run in parallel)

[B]

```
val f = for {
  _ <- Future { someTask1() }
  _ <- Future { someTask2() }
  _ <- Future { someTask3() }
} yield ()

Await.result(f, Duration.Inf)
```

How should I modify A so it runs as expected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that some circler references while creating the `query` objects were causing this problem.

Answer (score 3):

I couldn't reproduce your issue, but the reason for weird behaviour might be that your syntax in the first example is not exactly correct. You should write your first for-comprehension like:

```
val f = for {
  _ <- f1
  _ <- f2
  _ <- f3
} yield ()
```

But for-comprehension works sequentially and the only reason your futures run in parallel in your first example is that Futures start eagerly (*"Future starts now"*).

If you want to make sure Futures will execute in parallel use `Future.sequence`:

```
val f = Future.sequence(
  List(
    Future { someTask1() },
    Future { someTask2() },
    Future { someTask3() }
  )
)
```

Comment: oh, I pasted incorrectly. Now I corrected the code.

Comment: Still, it should work, so the problem must be somewhere else. Can you maybe share what do you do in your futures?

Comment: I have added a simplified inner recursive function that I am using

Comment: This function is returning `Future[Unit]`, yes?

Comment: no, it is returning just Unit. The function is wrapped in Future in the end, so eventually, Future[Unit] to be precise

Answer (score 0):

The problem does not lie within the for-comprehension, but with your tasks. Potentially there's some kind of deadlock from running them in parallel, but I'd triple check first that they don't end up in an infinite loop. Looking at your example, that could easily happen if `query.run.value` never returns empty, and then the recursion will continue forever. If *any* of `f1`, `f2` and `f3` don't resolve, then `f` will of course never resolve either.

Comment: What might be causing the deadlock? Each task is independent of each other and fetches records from different tables, not the same tables.

Comment: Like I said, deadlock seems unlikely, although possible. You have a magical `val query = //query to fetch data from database` in your example code. Can you prove that your variable will always be assigned a query that returns empty sooner or later? If not, start there, because hunting deadlocks will be a waste of time if you don't know that your code will terminate.